# Why "position: sticky" works fine for left, but not for top?

Tags: html, css, position, sticky

I have an HTML table inside de div with specific sizes. When I scroll to the right, I want the first column to keep position. It's working fine. But when I scroll down, I want the first row to keep position and I can't achieve it.
Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong ?

Here's an extract from my css :

```
.ordotableHorizonTh {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 1px;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 285px;
    height: 46px;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: bold;
 }

 .ordotableHorizonTd {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 1px;
    z-index: 500;
    width: 85px;
    height: 46px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing my problem : https://jsfiddle.net/jaobqweg/

Comment: you need to make the `tr` sticky top not the td

Comment: Oh.... It was so easy ! Thanks a lot.